# Selenium if sentence and the click else find some other and click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with Selenium Webdriver. Following code is where my headache is at:

```
    boolean FindPrimary=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='started_in_business_view']/p")) != null;

    if(FindPrimary){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='started_in_business_view']/p")).click();

    }

    else 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='started_in_business_view']/div")).click();
```

---

The excepted result that I want to achieve is that the driver searches for the element and clicks it. And if it doesn´t find it ,the driver clicks the optional element.

Comment: If the WebElement is not found then you will get NoSuchElementException before checking it with null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you received a NoSuchElement in the first line.

```
boolean findPrimary=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='started_in_business_view']/p")).size() > 0;
if(findPrimary){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='started_in_business_view']/p")).click();
    }
    else 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='started_in_business_view']/div")).click();
```

Comment: Works like a summer wind.Thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

I would do it with

```
try{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='started_in_business_view']/p")).click();
} catch (Exception exc) {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='started_in_business_view']/div")).click();
}
```

if you're xpaths are correct, should work...